# Git: how to make a branch that collaborators can work on?

Tags: git

So, all I want to do is make a dev branch that when my friend fetches and pulls, will get the dev branch and is able to push with it so we can work on updates together.

Answer (score 1):

Well, its no more complicated than `git checkout -b newBranchName`

You might do well to read through the first 2 or 3 chapters of the GitPro book, available for free on the web, https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Getting-Started-About-Version-Control

Comment: Well, my friend says that when he fetches and pulls, he cant enter the new branch.

Comment: Again, have your friend or you read the book and post with more specific questions.